# What is the size of the largest numbers (integers) that current supercomputers can handle?

Tags: integers

I am interested in designing number theory experiments and interested in knowing current capabilities of supercomputers to handle extremely large numbers. I'm interested in learning the size of the numbers (i.e. the largest possible) that their variables can hold. (Not things like what is the largest prime number so far discovered by a supercomputer)

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with them. A Computer Algebra System (CAS) like Maple, Sage or Mathematica can deal with infinite size quantities in algebraic computations.

Comment: And you don't need a supercomputer to do that. There is at least one CAS that runs on the Apple Watch!

Comment: A single byte can store about 2.4 decimal digits. Apart from the fact that my wife would kill me, I could buy a computer with 1.5TB of RAM which can store about 3.6 trillion decimal digits of numbers. Many algorithms will need several numbers to be stored. So if you have an algorithm that needs to store 10 numbers, that's 360 billion decimal digits each in RAM. Many algorithms will work quite well with storage on an SSD, and I can attach several 60TB SSDs to a computer. Each holding 144 trillion decimal digits. Computer and four of these drives will be less than $200,000.